# Can I use the hashcode of an object as a cache key?

Tags: c#

can I use the hashcode of an object as a cachekey?

My assumption is that the hash would be the same for each Criteria, where the property values are the same?

Something like this:

```
function void Method1(Criteria criteria)
{ 
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        string CacheKey = "Method1-" + criteria.GetHashCode();

        if(cache.Contains(CacheKey))
            return (IEnumerable)cache.Get(CacheKey);
        else
        {
            IEnumerable stuff = repository.GetStuff();
 
            CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.0);
            cache.Add(CacheKey, stuff, cacheItemPolicy);
 
            return stuff;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your assumption?

Comment: What does the documentation for `Criteria` say about what `GetHashCode` returns?  Don't assume.

Comment: I would recommend `override GetHashCode()` if you are going to do this.

Answer (score 4):

> can I use the hashcode of an object as a cachekey?

No. Not without an additional failsafe.

> My assumption is that the hash would be the same for each Criteria,
>   where the property values are the same?

The assumption is wrong. Hash codes are required to be the same only for objects that implement `IEquatable<T>` and are equal, but even in that case they are *not required* to be different for objects that are unequal. Since in the general case the number of possible different `Criteria` instances is infinite while the range of the hash code is finite, there will always be collisions due to the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `GetHashCode` implemented right returns the same `int` value for the same object state (e.g. the same properties values). However, you can't assume that every object with different state/values will have different hash code. It's possible to have the same hash code for different objects, even when `GetHashCode` is implemented right.